# Why doesn't a quoted line `> 1 1` format as quoted?

Tags: support, markdown

I was just editing/formatting the question [Using basic arrays to sort an input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29321749/using-basic-arrays-to-sort-a-input) and came across a peculiarity.  I was trying to enter a line as:

```
> 1 1
```

so that it would appear as a quoted block, like this:

> 1 1

but on SO, using my browsers (Firefox, Chrome and Safari — latest versions — on Mac OS X 10.10.2), I got output like:

[image]

instead of like it displays above here on MSO.  Do you see the glitch, or is that a quirk in my browsers (restart needed, or reboot needed?), or is there some other bug here?

Comment: The phrase "polishing a turd" comes to mind.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The user had somehow gotten a couple of soft hyphens into their text. The actual text was:

```
(soft hyphen)> (soft hyphen)1 1
```

Comment: Curious, but sounds reasonable.  I'd done some 'delete what is there and retype it' style editing without success, which puzzled me.  I'd go back and have another go at it, but I see you've already fixed it, so clearly I hadn't quite done enough remove and retype editing.  Thanks!